# How to get around 'Only Parameterless constructors and initializers...' error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to write a LINQ query that returns the rows where the "DateDue" field is less than 8 days from the current date.  The DateDue field can be null.  Here's my query:

```
var employees = (from u in Session.Context.Users
                join cu in Session.Context.CompanyUsers
                    on u.UserId equals cu.UserId
                join c in Session.Context.Companies
                    on cu.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId
                join uc in Session.Context.UserCourses
                on cu.CompanyUserId equals uc.CompanyUserId
                join crs in Session.Context.Courses
                on uc.CourseId equals crs.CourseId
                join so in Session.Context.ServicesOffereds
                    on crs.ServicesOfferedId equals so.ServicesOfferedId
                join jt in Session.Context.JobTitles
                    on u.JobTitleId equals jt.JobTitleId
                let DaysBeforeExpiring = (new DateTime(
                                        DateTime.Now.Year,
                                        uc.DateDue.HasValue ? uc.DateDue.Value.Month : DateTime.Now.Month,
                                        uc.DateDue.HasValue ? uc.DateDue.Value.Day : DateTime.Now.Day) - DateTime.Now).TotalDays
                where DaysBeforeExpiring < 8
                where c.ParentId == companyId || c.CompanyId == companyId
                where cu.IsActive
                where uc.Passed == false &&
                    uc.DateDue > DateTime.Now &&
                    uc.DateCompleted == null
                select new NonCompliantEmployeesModel()
                {
                    UserId = u.UserId,
                    UserCourseId = uc.UserCourseId,
                    JobTitle = jt.JobTitle1,
                    CompanyId = cu.CompanyId,
                    CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                    FirstName = u.FirstName,
                    LastName = u.LastName,
                    State = u.State,
                    EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress,
                    IsActive = cu.IsActive,
                    ServiceOffered = so.ServiceName,
                    DueDate = uc.DateDue,
                    Days = DaysBeforeExpiring
                });
```

But when I run the project, I get the `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.` error message.  I believe it has to do with the fact I'm creating a new `DateTime` object in the query but I don't know how to get around it.

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using that `let` clause at all, you might want to consider using the [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487052(v=vs.110).aspx) function of the `SqlFunctions` class, which was built specifically for doing more complex LINQ to Entities queries. Namely, you would want to be doing the following in your `where` clause:

```
where SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", DateTime.Now, uc.DateDue) < 8
```

The best part of this function, in my opinion, is the fact that the `DateTime` parameters are all nullable, so you won't even need to bother making a null check first.